# Blit image on invisible tkinter window

Tags: python, image, tkinter, window, transparent

I want to make an image blit on the screen with no window, and the workaround I have currently is to create a tkinter window and make it transparent and then trying to blit an image on it.
This is my code right now:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.wait_visibility(root)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(root, image=img)

panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.0)
root.mainloop()
```

The thing is that all the child widgets of root inherit the alpha value, and that is not what I want. Is there any way I can override the value from root to make the panel visible?

(I have tried doing this same thing with wx and pygame, didn't work)

Comment: Do you mean you have more windows associated with root in your program ? One way i can see is you create a toplevel window and add your label with image there with transparent alpha. Withdraw root when program is starting and show transparent toplevel

Comment: Did you try `root.overrideredirect(1)` instead of setting `alpha` if you want a borderless window?